# "Email This" button with sideways counter

Tags: email, sharing, sharepoint

I've been asked to build a design that has a "share this" area like below:

[image: share this stuff]

I've built every aspect except the Email part of it -- any idea how best to do that? I've found http://getmailcounter.com/, but that displays a counter above. I'd personally just do a link, but it seems they're wanting some sort of analytics built in...

Failing that, does anyone know of some sort of sharing system that looks like that and has all of those options? I'd just use [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com), but its designs don't look very close to that... Thanks!

Related: [How to implement an email this link button](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17470/how-to-implement-an-email-this-link-button)

Comment: You would like to build a counter yourself? If this is the question, why dont you increment a counter in the DB every time you successfully send an email? Sorry if I did not get the question correctly

Comment: I'm not wanting to build the counter myself; that's why I'm asking this question. I'm hoping there's some web-based drop-in-place system (Kind of like AddThis) that does what I'm wanting

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the custom options for addthis? http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381238-addthis-toolbox#.UH13Nfl27Eh